# unknown column 'beginVol' in 'field list' using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I've looked all over to solve this problem and couldn't find anything.

I'm using Sequelize through node to host a backend service. When I make an api call to my service I get the error "Unknown column 'beginVol' in 'field list'."

Here is the code for my model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const tankChange = sequelize.define(
      "tank_change",
      {
        ID: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true
        },
        tank: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        capacity: {
          type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        },
        beginVol: {
          field: 'beginVol',
          type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        },
        endVol: {
          type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        },
        salesVol: {
          type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        },
        readingVol: {
          type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        },
        dailyPer: {
          type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        },
        date: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
        }
      },
      {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
      }
    );
  
    return tankChange;
  };
```

Here is a screenshot of my table columns

[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS3vs.png)

Finally, here is the command that runs when I try to make an API call

```
SELECT `ID`, `tank`, `capacity`, `beginVol`, `endVol`, `salesVol`, `readingVol`, `dailyPer`, `date` FROM `tank_change` AS `tank_change` WHERE `tank_change`.`ID` = '53';
```

When I plug this command directly into my MySQL CLI it works just fine. This tells me it has to be something with Sequelize but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why you have  field: `'beginVol'`, in your model file try to remove it if it's not necessary and than try to execute

Comment: 'beginVol' is necessary and it is a column in my original table.

Comment: I am saying that you have column beginVol in that column name you have specified a 
field with type what is use of that `field` `field: 'beginVol',type: Sequelize.FLOAT,`